# How to downgrade Java version 1.6.0_36 to 1.6

Tags: 14.04, java, openjdk, downgrade

I am trying to compile the Android source code version 4.2 in my Ubuntu  14.04. The compilation step is unsuccessful throwing following in terminal.

```
Your version is: java version "1.6.0_36".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.
```

**So, how can I downgrade Java 1.6.0_36 (OPENJDK) to 1.6 (OPENJDK)?**

OS version:

```
#uname -ar
Linux XXX-VirtualBox 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: In can barely imagine that downgrading would help here … Can you please elaborate on what exactly you have tried and what exactly has happened then?

Comment: @Chriki, Downgrading is the only solution. To build Android version 4.2 I need to have exact java 1.6. I downloaded Android source code, ran the env script and finally ran "make" command. Do you know how can I downgrade the Java version? Please let me know.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the package you are trying to build and the exact instructions you have followed?

Comment: @Chriki, Is it possible to downgrade the Java (openjdk) version to 1.6.0 ? 
If so, how? That is the only question  :( 
I followed the instructions given here https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html :

# check out the source code using 'repo' binary.
# then : source build/envsetup.
# finally : make.


Error thrown is here : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6a46d52eeaaf62605124

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess the issue is not the Java version itself but rather the used JDK. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13136237/1797912) suggests that older Android versions require the **Oracle JDK** to build. Reading between the lines of [the “Installing the JDK” section](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#installing-the-jdk) of the official Android source documentation suggests the same: “To develop older versions of Android, download and install the corresponding version of the [Java JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html)” – note the link to the Oracle website at the end … that could have been made clearer.

So, in essence you should get the Oracle JDK and make sure that your build uses that instead of the OpenJDK you currently use. [This other Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20195622/1797912) explains a way to do this:

> 1.) If you’ve already installed OpenJDK . Remove it by running this command:
>   `sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`
>
> 2.) Then:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
> ```
>
> Then update:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> 3.) Select which version you want
>   To install Oracle Java 8:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
> ```

I guess Oracle JDK 8 will work, but you can also install the older JDK 6 to be on the safe side.